Automatic gain control and Tayloe detector
For a recent project, we need to build an RF IQ frontend to detect tones at 500kHz sent by a nearby transmitter. We want to use the Tayloe IQ detector followed by baseband ADC conversion to be able to further process the signals at the DSP side.
I have been studying the Tayloe detector design and I find it superior to alternatives and very simple to build, especially at our mid-frequency range.
Our circuit needs to detect and measure near-field magnetic pulses at around 500 kHz, with a bandwidth of less than 1 kHz. We’ll use an LC resonant ferrite antenna, and some low-noise JFET voltage follower to lower the impedance and attack the detector.
We expect some 140 dB dynamic range at the input, and therefore we will have to add automatic gain control to the RF frontend before reaching the ADCs. We need to have control over the gain of this AGC to be able to measure the strength of the input signal. My idea was to have this gain regulated from my uC or DSP after ADC conversion, then sent to some VGA chip or a cascade of them.
The question is: where do you think it is more appropriate to situate this VGA:

(a) before the detector?
(b) after the detector?
(c) using the detector amplifiers of the Tayloe detector as the AGC amplifiers?
(d) some AGC before the detector and some AGC after (e.g., 0–40 dB on each side)?

In particular, how is this decision going to impact the overall noise characteristics?
Your thoughts on this topic would be very valuable for us!
For some necessary context, here’s an expectation of our input signals:

Max Vin = 4,3 Vrms  — when Tx and Rx are 50 cm apart
Min Vin = 0,5 uVrms — when Tx and Rx are 100 m apart

This input range is around 140 dB wide.
Also, we will be using single power supply, either 3.3 V or 5 V.
We can adjust the signal amplitudes beforehand to match the input range of the final circuit, via e.g. a suitable transformer, which would also ease impedance matching.
Thank you.

Expectation of half-microvolt at 500kHz seems highly optimistic, even in a low-noise environment.
AGC should be applied early. Here's one suggestion of a programmable step-attenuator. You might choose a log-sequence pot. If you expect a 4.3Vrms input with a preamp/buffer powered by +5V, some attenuation right at the resonator would be required, even before buffering.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thanks glen.
The expected voltage is after the resonator, with a Q of around 80. Bear in mind that the distance is just some tens of meters.
Without the resonator, the open-circuit EMF of the antenna is around 3,5nV

These numbers are taken from the Tx and antenna specs. I also checked in the lab at short distances, where signal is greater than noise, and they match.

Thanks for the suggested attenuator. What do you think of this pipeline:

LC resonator
Programmable attenuator -- accounts for large voltges at short distance
AGC -- accounts for most dynamic range esp. at long distances
Tayloe IQ detection
ADC
DSP


Cascaded step attenuators are common (example: spectrum analyzer front end). A good ADC might accommodate much of the required dynamic range, while preceding programmable attenuators address the rest. Environmental noise will set the least-detectable limit. You may need extra effort to reject huge AM broadcast-band signals - they are close-by compared to 500 kHz.
